# swift Dictionary error

Tags: ios, swift

I have this func:

```
typealias KeyValue = Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
func response( response: NSHTTPURLResponse!, data: AnyObject!, error: NSError! ) {

    var resData = data as NSDictionary

    if( resData["status"] as Int == 1 ){

        var content = resData["content"] as Array<KeyValue>

        for player in content {

            let id      : Int       = player["id"]
            let score   : Int       = player["score"]
            let name    : String    = player["name"]

            players[ id ]!.setName( name )
            players[ id ]!.setScore( score )
        }

    } else {
        println( resData["error"] )
    }

    self.playersList.reloadData()
}
```

and i'm getting this error:
'(String, AnyObject)' is not convertible to 'Int'
on this lines

```
let id      : Int       = player["id"]
let score   : Int       = player["score"]
let name    : String    = player["name"]
```

I can't figure out why
content is Array
 -> player is KeyValue
 -> player is Dictionary
 -> player["id"] is AnyObject

so why he think that player["id"] is '(String, AnyObject)'??

Thanks

### UPDATE

Change to this fix that error:

```
let id      = player["id"]!     as Int
let score   = player["score"]!  as Int
let name    = player["name"]!   as String
```

But now i'm getting this in run-time:

```
Thread 5: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT,subcode=0xdefe)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`player` in your loop is an instance of `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`. So values stored in that dictionary are instances of `AnyObject`.

In this line:

```
let id : Int = player["id"]
```

you are trying to make an implicit cast from `AnyObject` to `Int`, which is not possible. The correct way to handle that is to:

1. Unwrap the value extracted from the dictionary (it can be `nil` if the key doesn't exist)
2. explicitly cast to `Int`

So that line should be fixed as follows:

```
let id : Int = player["id"]! as Int
```

which can also be shortened as:

```
let id = player["id"]! as Int
```

Similar rules apply for `score` and `name`

**Addendum** - as per your last error, probably it is caused by the fact that a key is not in the dictionary. Try using optionals like this:

```
let id = (player["id"] as AnyObject?) as? Int
let score = (player["score"] as AnyObject?) as? Int
let name = (player["name"] as AnyObject?) as? String
```

You have 3 optional variables, which get `nil` if the corresponding expression at the right side evaluates to `nil`. If that works, use the debugger to check which key is not in the dictionary

Comment: Its fixed that error.. but now i'm having error in run-time on the same line:
Thread 5: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT,subcode=0xdefe)

Comment: Pls check addition to my answer